# Discord 'Cannot send messages to this user' error

Tags: discord.js

I don't know exactly how to use catch err, send a message instead of giving an error when it blocks the bot in the private message I want to do.
This code:

```
     try{        
     message.member.send("trying private message.")
     } catch(e) {
     message.channel.send("Your private message is closed.");
     };
```

When I get an error the catch err part doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sending a message returns a promise. You can handle the promise error by using the `catch()` method.

```
message.member.send('Trying to send a DM!')
   .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
      message.channel.send('Your DMs are closed.');    
   });
```

Comment: The apostrophe was wrong and it worked when I fixed it